# extracting text with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the text from this html using bs4, i am new to this and cant seem to get it, any help much appreciated.

```
<div class="results">
            <span class="toggle" ng-click="display.toggleConfig()">{{display.configText}}</span>


            <p ng-hide="insecure">It would take <span ng-show="config.calculationsOriginal">a desktop PC</span> about <span class="main">{{time}}</span> to crack your password</p>
            <a class="tweet-me" ng-hide="insecure" href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=It would take a desktop PC about {{time}} to crack my password!%0d%0dhttp://hsim.pw">[Tweet Result]</a>

            <p ng-show="insecure">Your password would be cracked almost <span class="main">Instantly</span></p>
            <a class="tweet-me" ng-show="insecure" href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=My password would be cracked almost instantly!%0d%0dhttp://hsim.pw">[Tweet Result]</a>

            <span class="toggle" ng-click="display.toggleDetails()">{{display.detailsText}}</span>
        </div>

        <ul ng-show="display.details">
            <li><strong>Length:</strong> {{length}} characters</li>
            <li><strong>Character Combinations:</strong> {{characters}}</li>
            <li><strong>Calculations Per Second:</strong> {{calcsPerSecond}}</li>
            <li><strong>Possible Combinations:</strong> {{possibleCombinations}}</li>
        </ul>

        <ul ng-show="checks">
            <li ng-repeat="check in checks" class="{{check.type}}">
                <h2 ng-bind-html-unsafe="check.title"></h2>
                <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="check.wording"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

What I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source) #Example extract crack time with CSS selector
crack_time = soup.select('results') 
print crack_time[0].text
```

Comment: i am using selenium and trying the code below with bs4  soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
#Example extract crack time with CSS selector
crack_time = soup.select('results')
print crack_time[0].text

Comment: only text, like full text of this??

Comment: yes, its from 'howsecureismypassword'..when i input the password, the resulting text pops up and i would like to extract it using bs4

Comment: Hello @pam, welcome to the site! You appear to be having difficulty asking good questions on StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: `text = [s.text for s in soup.find_all('p')]`

Comment: no worries, you're welcome, I added the code you tried to your question, it will help you when you ask a question if you add the code you have tried to.

Comment: another quick one padraic ,if i just wanted to extract from the ng-hide line, how would i go about it..the output should be something like "it would take a desktop 'time' to crack your password

Comment: Let's not turn the comments section into a Q&A. This style is what IRC was invented for, not Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear where the time actually is in the html, but it looks like it is in a `<span>` with `class="main"`. There are two of these and they can easily be extracted:

```
for x in soup.findAll("span",{"class":"main"}):
    print x.text
```

Gives:

```
{{time}}
Instantly
```

If you want all the text from the object, try:

```
soup.get_text()
```

which will recursively pull all the text from the object and its children.